# Difference between a 'hobo' and a 'homeless person'

Tags: differences

In dictionary,

> *hobo*: One who wanders from place to place without a permanent home or a means of livelihood. [(Wordnik)](https://www.wordnik.com/words/hobo)
>
> *homeless person*: one who has no home or haven.

I think that a *hobo* is a kind of very dirty person walking or living in the street or a corner of a station, while the homeless person simply has no home to live in, but still wears decent clothes, etc. (Maybe not super clean, but definitely cleaner than a hobo)

I think the dictionary is missing something in its definition...

Can we use these two terms interchangeably?

Comment: Yes, they are synonyms. However, *hobo* is bit of an old fashioned term.

Comment: @Elliott, I would consider _hobo_ a perfectly normal, colloquial word (at least in AmE, but also I think in BrE). Not old-fashioned at all.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Gotten to know many who spange?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet 'hobo' sounds very Depression era to me, riding the rails with all possessions tied up in a handkerchief at the end of a stick.

Comment: As a side note, what dictionary is that from? *Always* give credit where credit is due. Moderators are instructed to *delete on sight* your entire post if it contains material that's not properly attributed.

Comment: @Mitch, that too. But I have also heard many people refer to unkempt and ‘bum-looking’ homeless people in general as hobos. In that sense, of course, it's a highly pejorative word, like bum or tramp (which I do think is old-fashioned), whereas the older sense is more neutral.

Comment: Janus Bahs Jacquet, the word *hobo* is not used in BrE. It's American.

Comment: @Tristan: Too right! But I thought even Americans abandoned it after the war. To me it's just a word from the Depression - I didn't realise anyone still used it in ordinary conversation. To describe *who?* - no-one bums around on freight trains any more, do they?

Comment: @Mitch: The word you're looking for is [bindle](http://encyclopedia.thefreedictionary.com/bindle).

Comment: @Fumble, actual hobos are probably quite rare these days. But the figurative use is very much alive, particularly, perhaps, among young people. If you're having a bad hair day, for example, it is not uncommon (in AmE, but I've also heard it used by Brits) to say, “Jeez, I look like a hobo!”.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet right, and for someone to use 'Jeez, I look like a homeless person' would sound very insensitive nowadays because it is for real.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The OED makes clear that the term 'hobo' has been primarily an American one, first recorded in 1889.

The name appears to have arisen from people formerly called 'tramps' referring to themselves as 'hoboes'.

1889   Ellensburgh (Washington) Capital 28 Nov. 2/2   The tramp has changed his name, or rather had it changed for him, and now he is a ‘Hobo’.

1891   ‘J. Flynt’ in Contemp. Rev. Aug.,   The tramp's name for himself and his fellows is Hobo, plural Hoboes.

Essential to the notion of a hobo is vagrancy. Though the OED is not explicit on the matter,  the term has been far less used in Britain. Throughout most of the time that it existed in the United States, the equivalent British term would have been 'tramp'.

The OED's last recorded instance of its use is in 1972, suggesting that it may be far less common than it once was.

The term 'homeless' means literally 'without a home', and carries none of the pejorative connotations that 'tramp' or 'hobo' once did. It may be used more specifically in the United Kingdom where local authorities have been legally obliged, for several decades, to provide homeless people with some form of housing. Such provided housing has not always been accepted and hence it has not been unusual, in Britain's large cities, to see homeless people sleeping rough.

In Australia a *swaggy* is similar to an American *hobo*. This may be of interest re *Dingo's breakfast*.

*Dingo’s breakfast has recently been added to the Oxford English dictionary. Dingo’s breakfast is an Australian phrase that actually means no breakfast at all. A dingo’s breakfast originated with stories of the Australian swaggy, or transient worker, who crossed the land looking for work to pay for his next meal, often he was without provisions in the morning. Just like the dingo who lived on a subsistence diet, the swaggy would rise and find nothing to eat, so his “breakfast” consisted of “a scratch, a piss, and a good look around.”* From [Grammarist](https://grammarist.com/idiom/dingos-breakfast/#:%7E:text=A%20dingo%27s%20breakfast%20originated%20with,without%20provisions%20in%20the%20morning.)

Comment: 'homeless' may not be pejorative, and rather matter-of-fact, but it is more disturbing in its frank reality.

Comment: @Mitch But 'homeless' simply describes a logistical fact. And such people do, in Britain anyway, receive considerable support. The terms hobo, and the like, imply levels of personal degeneracy.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but I'm not sure I agree about implications. What I'm trying to say about the difference between 'hobo' and 'homeless' is that even if their denotations are identical (I don't think they are) if you describe someone nowadays as a 'hobo', that is more figurative and 'homeless' is more literal, and so the implications are a bit different.

Comment: @mitch. My guess is that hobos were defined by the depression years of the 1930s in the same way that tramps were. The reason that a 'tramp' tramps from place to place is not that they enjoy physical exercise and the fresh air. The attached essay by George Orwell (formerly Eric Blair), 'A day in the Life of a Tramp' will explain what 'tramping' was like and its causes, in those days.  [tramp] (http://theorwellprize.co.uk/george-orwell/by-orwell/essays-and-other-works/a-day-in-the-life-of-a-tramp/)

Comment: It is worth noting that the word hobo was a sort of abbreviated portmanteau of "HOmeward BOund" referring to soldiers from the American Civil War making their way from wherever they were when the fighting ended. So, mobility is 100% implied by the term.

Comment: @IchabodE See my edit to the answer.

Comment: Homeless can mean someone who's couch surfing (sleeping in a makeshift bed with relatives or friends with no space of their own), staying in hostels for the indigent, or otherwise without a proper residence. A homeless person might be able to sleep indoors every night, but not have a home. A hobo at least in popular imagination would sleep rough or if they were lucky in a barn, shed, or other informal shelter.

Answer (score 5):

> A hobo is a migratory laborer and a tramp is a migratory non-laborer and a bum is a non-migratory non-laborer.

—"[Oklahoma Slim](http://hobonickels.org/hoffman.htm)," hobo

*Migratory* is a key quality of the hobo. Traditionally, hobos were known for "riding the rails," illegally hitching rides on freight trains to get from place to place. There is an imputed element of choice: to some extent, the hobo is a hobo because he (it is usually a man or a boy) enjoys traveling and sleeping under the stars. Hobos had their heyday in the early to mid-20th century in North America, and are much less common today for a variety of reasons.

The word *hobo* is sometimes used contemporarily today as a rough synonym for *homeless person*, probably because it's an inherently funny word that can take some of the edge off of a very unfunny topic (for example, Jon Stewart's frequent jokes about his [hobo-killing hobby](http://www.thedailyshow.com/watch/thu-january-9-2003/killed-a-hobo) are a lot less funny if you substitute the word "homeless").

Answer (score 3):

Hobos are peripatetic; homeless people are located in one location (but without a home); or at least there is no suggestion of travel.

Answer (score 0):

I've closevoted (General Reference), but

> [hobo](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hobo)  — n  , pl -bos , -boes
>   1.  a tramp; vagrant
>   2.  a migratory worker, esp an unskilled labourer

I don't see OP's exact wording there, but I got the above link [from here](http://www.kgbanswers.co.uk/what-is-a-hobo/11477581), so obviously either it *was* there, or the poster of the link was paraphrasing.

I won't bother citing a definition for *homeless person*. Definitions for the individual words can be studied (were the Jews "homeless" before Israel?), but there are obscure *legal* definitions too. In the UK, [Local authorities have a legal duty to provide help to certain people who are homeless or threatened with homelessness under the 1996 Housing Act.](http://homeless.org.uk/local-authority-advice#.UurzZnDCWZE) Obviously they have to know *exactly* what the words mean there - but it probably won't be what everyone else thinks.

---

The long and short of it is that *hobo* is a dated Americansim that was never very close in meaning to the modern concept of *homeless person*. Which to my mind covers everything from [hundreds if not thousands of people in the UK "sleeping rough"](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/73200/Rough_Sleeping_Statistics_England_-_Autumn_2012.pdf) to [millions of Syrians](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-middle-east-23937972) who no longer live in their "home" (even the "lucky" ones - displaced but at least still within their *homeland*).

Comment: I can't quite agree that _hobo_ was "never very close in meaning to the modern concept of homeless person." I'd characterize the two terms of overlapping in meaning; that is, a hobo is one kind of homeless person, but there are several others, as you point out, such as refugees.

Comment: @J.R.: Well, as I cited, *hobo* has/had at least two recognisably distinct senses. Incidentally, OED has only *one* definition: *orig. Western U.S. ‘An idle shiftless wandering workman, ranking scarcely above the tramp’.* ([Look **that** up in your Funk and Wagnalls!](http://www.tv.com/shows/rowan-and-martins-laugh-in/) :) I've never particularly associated hobos with homelessness in the sense of "*wanting* a home", any more than I'd think that about Wild West cowboys. They just live lives orthogonal to the concept of "Home Sweet Home" (or indeed, "An Englishman's home is his castle". :)

Comment: Do you need to want a home to be homeless? Though I agree that something like _vagrant_ might be a better synonym for _hobo_. (Incidentally, my thesaurus lists both _hobo_ and _homeless person_ as possible synonyms for _vagrant_).

Comment: Re _"I've closevoted (General Reference)"_: Is that a done thing, to CV and answer? Not a judgement, but I do wonder.

Answer (score 0):

Hobo's are people classified as "sleeping-rough" on the street or in bushland. But this classification may be limited to Australia.

A homeless person is a person without a fixed address. They may live in temporary accommodation(i.e. motels, hotels, caravan parks, etc), usually supported/subsidised by the state or a community group, which they could not do so by themselves.

A homeless person in a broader sense could be anyone who's been dispossed of a residence by any circumstance, while hobo can be viewed as a homeless person who's remained homeless primarliy because of personal reasons (i.e. drug use, lack of education, personal choice).

Answer (score 0):

I was born in 1949, and raised in a stable middle-class environment.  There were several terms used (by my elders, in this era) for people raised in less-stable situations.  "Hobos" (in this era) were regarded as tramps/vagrants but perhaps a little higher class than your everyday "tramp".  In particular, hobos were assumed to be folks who traveled around and were therefore familiar with fairly wide expanses of geography.  Among other things, they could often be hired to do (temporary) jobs that required a reasonable amount of skill and knowledge.

Answer (score -1):

I'd say that probably all hobos are homeless people, but we would not call all homeless people hobos.

Comment: And how would you distinguish the hobos from the homeless people?

Comment: so u believe that hobo has much worse living condition than homeless person?

Comment: Traditionally, a hobo would move from place to place doing odd jobs for money or food.  This is distinct from a beggar, who asked for money for nothing.